# Function that measures accuracy interval of a MacLaurin series?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k6b95wj82y

As you include more terms, the accuracy interval expands wider.
Is there a function that returns accuracy interval of a MacLaurin series, given the number of terms used?

Here is accuracy interval for using 1 to 10 terms:

1 - .5

2 - 1.4

3 - 2.25

4 - 3.2

5 - 4

6 - 5

7 - 5.7

8 - 6.44

9 - 7

10 - 8

The regression function for the given pairs is:

y = 0.818x + 0.539